# How to loop through JSON items and JSON subitems

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have the following JSON input

```
{
    "requestId": "453sdafwa234",
    "result": [
        {
            "seq": 0,
            "GUID": "081119bd-63a8-42ca-85de-5b4761234955",
            "amount": 1234,
            "externalId": "1234567890",
            "Status": "OK"
        },
        {
            "seq": 1,
            "GUID": "011119bd-42ca-63a8-85de-5b47111a8955",
            "amount": 5678,
            "externalId": "2345678901",
            "Status": "OK"
        }]
}
```

I want to loop through all `result` and then output the `externalId` key value.

I tried

```
json_op = json.loads(json_string)

for op in json_op:
    for r in op["result"]:
      print r["externalId"]
```

which did not work.

I also tried

```
json_op = json.loads(json_string)

for op in json_op:
    r.get["result"].get["externalId"]
```

But this also didnt work. What is the right way?

Comment: Your `json` has duplicate keys and once you load this into python as a `dict` only the last (`result`) is kept.

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected it.

Comment: for data in s['result']:
    print(data['externalId']).. s being the json

Comment: Once the json string parsed using `json.loads()`, what you have is a plain python dict (where on of the keys maps to a python list of python dicts). The fact it's been built from a json string is totally irrelevant, it's just plain python dicts and lists, both types being fairly well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First of all you have to import json lib at the beginning of your code.

Then, you are not iterating properly your dictionary object.

If you want to read your requestId key, just write

```
print(json_op['requestId'])
```

For iterating results:

```
json_op = json.loads(s)

print(json_op['requestId'])

for res in json_op['result']:
    print(res['seq'])
    print(res['GUID'])
    print(res['amount'])
    ...
```

Try and tell me something. I cannot run the code now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in json_op["result"]:
    print (i["externalId"])
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

s = """{
    "requestId": "453sdafwa234",
    "result": [
        {
            "seq": 0,
            "GUID": "081119bd-63a8-42ca-85de-5b4761234955",
            "amount": 1234,
            "externalId": "1234567890",
            "Status": "OK"
        },
        {
            "seq": 1,
            "GUID": "011119bd-42ca-63a8-85de-5b47111a8955",
            "amount": 5678,
            "externalId": "2345678901",
            "Status": "OK"
        }]
}"""

json_op = json.loads(s)

for item in json_op['result']:
    print(item['externalId'])
```

Output:

```
1234567890
2345678901
```

Answer (score 1):

Then why not list comprehension:

```
print([i["externalId"] for i in json_op["result"]])
```

Or want formatted:

```
print('\n'.join([i["externalId"] for i in json_op["result"]]))
```